# Some Database Tables Have dr_ prefix

Tags: database

Hello ive been messing about with drupa for 8 years now and im still YET to get a website to go live :( After about 10 reinstalls of my new website idea i was just about to go live and then i had a wee look in the database and ive noticed a load of tables prefixed dr_

I know some softulicious installs add this db prefix.

My site works well enough but the tables prefixed as per attached are  worry to me. Should they be a worry to me?

Can i fix it easily enough?

Thanks

[image: pic1]
[image: pic2]
[image: pic3]

ps all my other db tables are unprefixed which is the desired effect. All help appreciated as im close to startingmy site again from scratch :(

My electricity is about to get cut off for 12hrs so cant reply till then.

Comment: Why would you think having prefixes on the database tables is a problem? That's a _feature_ that Drupal provides, which you must have explicitly, intentionally taken advantage of for it to have happened in the first place

Comment: Nah by default if i install drupal via an installer that my web host provides me with Clive by default it wants to add dr_ to the db tables. I usually just remove that and install it without them which i belive is the behaviour of manually installing drupal. I think somewhere along the line ive imported things from old databases/installs of drupal and now im left with some things having the dr_ prefix and others (90% of my db) not having the dr_ prefix. If it wont cause me any problems then im fine with it i just dont want to continue this install to find that having dr_ and non dr_ tables in

Comment: my database is goign to cause me problems. I appreciate your response though. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can sometimes happen if you are using softaculous installer (or similar one-click installer provided by your web host). Perhaps you installed several instances of Drupal using the same database name, and just left the 'dr_' prefix in place for one by accident.

If I were you, I wouldn't worry too much about it. Having the additional tables there won't cause any problems with your Drupal installation (the one using the non-prefixed tables), and the 'dr_' prefixed tables won't increase in size as time goes on.

You should be able to safely leave them as they are, or, if you want to, remove them using phpMyAdmin to permanently delete (drop) the tables prefixed with 'dr_'.